# How can I label X-axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Question: I am trying to draw two graphs in which I want to label perfect positive correlation on x-axis in first graph and perfect negative correlation in second graph.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.6in,bottom=0.3in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in,headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain = 0:5]
\draw[<->] (-1,0) -- (5.5,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[<->] (0,-1) -- (0,5.5) node[right] {$y$};
\draw[color = blue, thick] (1,1) -- (2,2) -- (3,3) -- (4,4) -- (5,5);
\fill (1,1)  circle[radius=2pt];
\fill (2,2)  circle[radius=2pt];
\fill (3,3)  circle[radius=2pt];
\fill (4,4)  circle[radius=2pt];
\fill (5,5)  circle[radius=2pt];
\end{tikzpicture}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain = 0:5]
\draw[<->] (-1,0) -- (5.5,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[<->] (0,-1) -- (0,5.5) node[right] {$y$};
\draw[color = blue, thick] (1,5) -- (2,4) -- (3,3) -- (4,2) -- (5,1);
\fill (1,5)  circle[radius=2pt];
\fill (2,4)  circle[radius=2pt];
\fill (3,3)  circle[radius=2pt];
\fill (4,2)  circle[radius=2pt];
\fill (5,1)  circle[radius=2pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: look at the pgfplots package

Comment: just wanna a lable x-axis in same graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a second node when you draw the x-axis. `pos=0.6` means that it's placed just after the midway point of the path (0 is the start, 1 is the end).

```
\draw[<->] (-1,0) -- (5.5,0) node[right] {$x$} node[pos=0.6,below=3mm] {Perfect positive correlation};
```

If you're interested, you can make the code quite a bit shorter, by using  `\draw plot`, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.6in,bottom=0.3in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in,headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   % domain and samples applies to the plot commands below
   domain = 1:5,samples=5
   ]

\draw[<->] (-1,0) -- (5.5,0) node[right] {$x$} node[pos=0.6,below=3mm] {Perfect positive correlation};
\draw[<->] (0,-1) -- (0,5.5) node[right] {$y$};
\draw[color = blue, thick, mark=*]  plot(\x,\x);

\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
\draw[<->] (-1,0) -- (5.5,0) node[right] {$x$} node[pos=0.6,below=3mm] {Perfect negative correlation};
\draw[<->] (0,-1) -- (0,5.5) node[right] {$y$};
\draw[color = blue, thick, mark=*]  plot(\x,-\x+6);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```